# rigging - partial success need help

Tags: animation, rigging, pose-mode

My first rigging.  I have tried following a lot of the suggestions given here to try and rig this golem.

It consists of an inner lava model and an outer rock model which was obtained with a fracture quick effect and joining its results.

The rig is made from a human-modified rig.

Both models have been checked for - Removed Doubles, Recalculated Normals, Removed Subsurface Modifier, Ensured Positioning for the Mesh and Bones are all set to Zero and Scale to 1.

I partially succeeded in rigging the inner lava but I absolutely cannot manage to rig the full inner lava and rock models to the rig.

I am uploading the file.  If someone can give it a look and tell me what is wrong I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks

[image]

Comment: it looks like you have some double vertices on the big character, remove them and it works

Comment: I removed all the doubles using - Clean up /merge by distance in edit mode.  Is there another way to do it, please.?

Comment: yes, you need to increase the threshold a bit in the Operator box (bottom left of your 3D view once you've merged by distance

Comment: I managed to rig it after I cleaned it up as you said but some parts are not following the rig this time.  Any Idea why pls.  I posted a photo above too.

Comment: you often need to make some corrections, either in Weight Paint mode, or go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups and assign the vertices to the group they are supposed to be part of

Comment: Wanted to nonetheless say THANKS.  I am managing to correct all the non-moving parts with weight painting even if it took me quite a while to figure out how to do it.  Total noob on it bu having fun learning.